# Provide convenient way to get the current site URL in SEDE query

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Since Data Explorer allows us to create links to any of the ["unlinked pages"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) (like [suggested-edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74266), [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline), [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions) etc) it would be useful to have a convenient way to get the URL of the site currently selected in the SEDE.
I have recently created a query which does exactly that: [Get current site URL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58897/get-current-site-url). But its reusage in every query which requires that URL (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116975/158912) or [those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104579/158912)) looks like overkill to me. Instead I propose to add `se_site_url()` function or `##SiteURL##` variable (which will be populated with the selected site URL).

Comment: Seems straightforward enough to me...I'll look at getting an implementation together later today.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction, @Tim ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, since we already support arbitrary autolinking if your results have something like

```
http://example.com/|link text
```

I thought the easiest way to solve this problem was to introduce a `site://` protocol so you could return a column

```
'site://posts/' + CAST(Id AS nvarchar) + '/revisions|History for Post ' + 
CAST(Id AS nvarchar) AS [Revisions]
```

for instance, to produce links in the rendered form of the following Markdown:

```
[History for Post <id>](http://x.stackexchange.com/posts/<id>/revisions)
                        ^------------------------^ based on queried site
```

<s>I've [pushed out the change](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=a863f4cc9e3a41f8917a0ffad3684e19c7b1ae0f) to my project, but I'll need to chat with waffles to make sure he's alright with that approach before I can promise it'll end up in the actual Data Explorer.</s> You can see the above example in action in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65919).

Hopefully this approach works for your needs too - if you really need the site URL in variable form I don't see why that couldn't be done, but I thought this syntax was a little easier if the primary concern was link construction.

Comment: +1 for the `site://` protocol, it looks like an elegant solution to me. (I even think this approach could be extended beyond the SEDE, e.g. to support `post://` protocol in the asnwers or comments, but that's another story for another FR).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/faq is lagging behind. Is there a more complete documentation somewhere, that includes newer features such as this one, and is better organized than MSO posts?

Comment: @Gilles Not entirely, no. I'm interested in improving the documentation on Data Explorer itself to bring it completely up to date, but I haven't had the time to do so just yet. If anyone's interested in helping with that, please let me know.

Comment: @TimStone I might (not now, but in July). What already exists? How much familiarity with the language and framework do you think would be required? (I don't know C# or databases.)

Comment: @Gilles Cool. It's pretty much just what's on the site itself plus whatever's here on Meta (my "not entirely" was probably terrible word choice, in retrospect), and then whatever's left over that I'll have to provide additional detail on. Once we have something, I can take care of adding it to the actual site, but there's some initial effort in figuring out what's missing and compiling information from me/anyone else who's familiar with how it works into something user/documentation-friendly (which would be largely non-technical).

Comment: @Gilles Okay, this ended up taking a bit longer than expected, but [new documentation is pending a pull and deploy](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/10). Once it goes live, feel free to let me know if it looks like anything is missing.

Comment: @TimStone Neat, thanks. Oh, I never got around to looking at this stuff last year. Sorry if I gave you false hopes. Not going to happen much this July I'm afraid. But I will have a look at what you wrote when it's up.